# Lines of code and other metrics in F#

Tags: f#, code-metrics

How to get some nice statistics about my F# code?

I could imagine things like

- number of lines of my code
- number of files
- number of characters?
- number of functions, classes, modules etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use some simple shell utilities?

Answers in order

```
wc -l *.fs
ls -l *.fs | wc -l
wc -c *.fs
grep module *.fs | wc -l
grep type *.fs | wc -l
grep "^let\|member" *.fs | wc -l
```

**Update:** Some examples for recursive folders - I hope the pattern is obvious

```
wc -l `find . -name "*.fs" `
find . -name "*.fs" | wc -l
wc -c `find . -name "*.fs" `
grep module `find . -name "*.fs" ` | wc -l
```

Comment: Nice! How do I run it? I use Windows 7 + VS 2010

Comment: These are all standard unix command line tools.  They are all included in cygwin at http://www.cygwin.com/.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. Is there a way how to recursively call the commands on all sub-folders?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an F# version which counts both `fs` and `fsx` files recursively (assuming you have F# runtime installed):

```
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let rec allFiles dir =
    seq { yield! Directory.GetFiles dir
          yield! Seq.collect allFiles (Directory.GetDirectories dir) }

let rgType = new Regex(@"type", RegexOptions.Compiled)
let rgModule = new Regex(@"module", RegexOptions.Compiled)
let rgFunction = new Regex(@"^let|member", RegexOptions.Compiled)

let count (rg: Regex) s =
    s |> rg.Matches |> fun x -> x.Count

type Statistics = {
        NumOfLines: int; NumOfFiles: int;
        NumOfChars: int; NumOfTypes: int;
        NumOfModules: int; NumOfFunctions: int;
    } 

let getStats =
    allFiles 
    >> Seq.filter (fun f -> f.EndsWith ".fs" || f.EndsWith ".fsx")
    >> Seq.fold (fun acc f -> 
                    let contents = f |> File.ReadLines
                    { NumOfLines = acc.NumOfLines + Seq.length contents; 
                      NumOfFiles = acc.NumOfFiles + 1;
                      NumOfChars = acc.NumOfChars + Seq.sumBy String.length contents;
                      NumOfTypes = acc.NumOfTypes + Seq.sumBy (count rgType) contents;
                      NumOfModules = acc.NumOfModules + Seq.sumBy (count rgModule) contents;
                      NumOfFunctions = acc.NumOfFunctions + Seq.sumBy (count rgFunction) contents; } 
                        ) { NumOfLines = 0; NumOfFiles = 0; 
                            NumOfChars = 0; NumOfTypes = 0; 
                            NumOfModules = 0; NumOfFunctions = 0 }
```

Comment: I think your `let` regex won't be correct.  I think it is more correct if you anchor it so that the `let` must be at the start of a line.

Comment: Thanks. The regex isn't exhaustive since it doesn't recognize `static let` or differentiate between functions and values.

Answer (score -2):

Because F# compile to IL code and Common Type System (CTS) and [PDB files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx), F# assemblies can be analyzed by the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Default.aspx) and you'll get [82 code metrics](http://www.ndepend.com/Metrics.aspx) about your code (+ all [others features of the tool](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx)). A free trial version is available [here](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx).

*Disclaimer, I am a member of the NDepend Team.*

Comment: well, nice idea to recur to IL code analysis, but due to the way the F# compiler produces code, most code metrics based on IL will be meaningless.